Linear map in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is orthogonal can be composed out of two reflections
$(V,s)$ is a three-dimensional Euclidean vector space and $a$ is normalized. A reflection $\sigma_a$ is defined in the following way:
$\sigma_a: V \rightarrow V, \, v \mapsto v - 2 s(v, a)a$
$f$ is a linear map defined on V with  $\det(f) = \det(f^2)$. Show that there exist reflections  $r_1 , r_2 \in \text{End}(V)$  such that  $f = r_1 \circ r_2$.
I should utilize the following facts:

$\sigma_a$ is a linear isometry
$\sigma_a^2 = \text{id}_V$
Every linear isometry of $V$ is a product of at most 3 reflections.

How I should roughly move forward?
So far I concluded that $f$ is isometric but now I am not sure how to make use of the hints to show that only 2 isometries are enough to compose $f$.
Thank you in advance.

a rotation has a positive determinant,  reflection is negative, must be an even number of reflections.
